# Extract key from JSON string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My table contains string in json format. I need to get the sum and average of each key.

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| id | json_data                                                                          | subject_id |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| 1  | {"id": "a", "value": "30"}, {"id": "b", "value": "20"}, {"id": "c", "value": "30"} | 1          |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| 2  | {"id": "a", "value": "40"}, {"id": "b", "value": "50"}, {"id": "c", "value": "60"} | 1          |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| 3  | {"id": "a", "value": "20"}                                                         | 1          |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Expected result is

```
    {"id": "a", "sum": 90, "avg": 30},
    {"id": "b", "sum": 70, "avg": 35},
    {"id": "c", "sum": 120, "avg": 40}
```

I've tried

```
SELECT (
  JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'sum', sum_data, 'avg', avg_data)
) FROM (
  SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.id") as id, 
    SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.sum_data")) as sum_data, 
    AVG(JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.avg_data")) as avg_data
  FROM Details 
  GROUP BY JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.id")
) as t
```

But no luck. How can I sort this out?

Comment: Your json is not proper.

Comment: Where are `$.sum_data` and `$.avg_data` in the JSON?

Comment: Are those supposed to be JSON arrays? If so, they need `[]` around them.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy way to extract the elements of a JSON array by a property value, and there's no way to group that way.

Comment: @Barmar sir, I read some references which says that Aliases  `sum_data`, `avg_data` maps the `JSON_OBJECT()`

Comment: Where do you read that? I can't find it in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: @Barmar https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: You must be referencing to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561075/6556397). But there is multidimensional array.

Comment: @quickSwap I refered, Its working when the row has single object, but ine is having multi objects per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input json needs to correct

```
create table json_sum (id int primary key auto_increment, json_data json);

insert into json_sum values (0,'[{"id": "a", "value": "30"}, {"id": "b", "value": "20"}, {"id": "c", "value": "30"}]');
insert into json_sum values (0,'[{"id": "a", "value": "40"}, {"id": "b", "value": "50"}, {"id": "c", "value": "60"}]');
insert into json_sum values (0,'[{"id": "a", "value": "20"}]');

select 
 json_object("id", jt.id, "sum", sum(jt.value), "avg", avg(jt.value))
 from json_sum, json_table(json_data, "$[*]" columns (
        row_id for ordinality,
        id varchar(10) path "$.id",
        value varchar(10) path "$.value")
) as jt
group by jt.id
```

Output:

```
json_object("id", jt.id, "sum", sum(jt.value), "avg", avg(jt.value))
{"id": "a", "avg": 30.0, "sum": 90.0}
{"id": "b", "avg": 35.0, "sum": 70.0}
{"id": "c", "avg": 45.0, "sum": 90.0}
```