# How to SUM array column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have problem sum of the amount from table books.

```
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| id | id_book   | title     | amount         |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | 1         |Book 1     |[[1],[1]]       |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

i want to sum column amount, anyone can help me? thx before.

Comment: Side note: if you can normalize your table structures. otherwise you will have to write very tricky SQL to parse out that JSON array

Comment: Parse (JSON_TABLE) then sum.

Comment: can u write the code?

Comment: What mysql version?

Comment: i already wrote some SQL code before on stackoverflow to parse out JSON but it is not pretty  and rather complex-> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9tcgRBJJcGrEsSPEAfmPzq/7   nest the complete SQL into a JOIN statement ( `INNER JOIN (SELECT ,,,,)  ON ... `) and join on id to get the data i assumming id to be a auto_increment in your table.. also note mine example supports up to 100 array elements if you need more you need to add a other `(
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  )`

Comment: ...   in the number generator

Comment: @ColouredPanda 5.0.12

Comment: You sure about that? It's outdated by 17 years

Comment: thanx @RaymondNijland. i have last question, how to sum if data [1,1] ?

Comment: @ColouredPanda yes sir

Comment: i found this one, define own function 
 to sum the data in json https://stackoverflow.com/a/55054131/16702058

Comment: thx @wuhoyt, how to use default mysql for SUM, without function