# SUM in MySQL where the column has two values "{"Population": 1780000}"

Tags: mysql, sum

It is as the title says, in a table provided to me, I'm trying to make a report and the turns up as 0.

I have been looking to figure out a way that works, my initial try was as basic as could be with:

```
SELECT SUM(info) 
FROM CITY
WHERE countrycode = 'AUS'
```

This was to the get the sum from the info column of the table where it has the data entered as in the title, {"Population": 1780000}, while it would be ideal to have two values in a single column, I need to work around this but have hit a brick wall.

I've tried using find_in_set but am struggling to figure how it is supposed to be worded, and I cannot find any resources going over the issue of having a word and number in it, and how to properly query the total sum of all values with this and have it not turn up as 0 despite there being 14 entries that all have a number in the info column.

For what I already tried, as stated above the basic sum count, then I tried formatting a find_in_set command I was unable to figure out how to query it for only the numbers alone, as examples I kept finding where largely for set things, such as a color, and not a numeric value that needed to be added up for a total and varied per entry.

Each time I was expecting that I would get the sum for the number values in the "info column" for the 14 entries, and not a 0 value.

EDIT: Sample text of the row and how the data is presented I am working with.

```
enter code here

|info|
|---------------------|
|{"Population": 99862}|
|{"Population": 9968485}|
|{"Population": 99669}|
|{"Population": 99578}|
|{"Population": 99387}|
```

Comment: Please add some rows of representative sample data as text.

Comment: You seem to have some kind of json-like structure in the info column. If that's the case, then you cannot simply use sum to get the the sum of population.

Comment: @P.SalmonI have added some rows of sample data as text.

Comment: @Shadow If a table is in a json-like structure for the info, what type of query should I look into to get the proper sum? Or is it a situation where due to its odd structure this type of query is not possible without removing the population tag in the info table?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490867/mysql-aggregated-sum-of-json-objects - although I would definitely store this data in a normalised manner. Json does not mix well with relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your info column is valid JSON, you can use the [`column-path operator ->`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax:%7E:text=column%2Dpath%20operator%20%2D%3E):

```sql
SELECT SUM(info->'$.Population')
FROM CITY
WHERE countrycode = 'AUS';
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jR2jXljN).

Comment: That worked! Manually checked the math for the result I was looking for, and it didn't miss anything. Thanks for this. Hopefully when I finish all the queries I need I won't need to work with this format again, but it's good to know how to work with it.